# C# Get functions from main application in external DLL

Tags: c#, dll, plugins

I have a main application which loads DLL files from a specified folder. I implemented an Interface which already allows me to call the functions from the DLL.

The problem is, that I don't know how to access variables and functions from my main application inside my DLL.

For example:
The database connection is declared in my main application. My plugin (DLL) should use this connection but I don't know how to access it.
Should I reference the .exe File?? Or is it a good idea to create a helper DLL, which exports the needed information somehow?

Main Application:

```
public void GetInstalledPlugins()
{
    List<IPlugin> actions = new List<IPlugin>();

    List<Assembly> allAssemblies = new List<Assembly>();
    string dllPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\Plugins\";

    if (!Directory.Exists(dllPath))
        return;

    foreach (string dll in Directory.GetFiles(dllPath, "*.dll"))
    {
        try
        {
            Assembly currentDLL = Assembly.LoadFrom(dll);
            Type[] types = currentDLL.GetExportedTypes();

            for (int i = 0; i <= types.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                Type type = types[i];

                if (type.GetInterface("IPlugin") != null && type != null)
                {
                    IPlugin new_action = currentDLL.CreateInstance(type.FullName) as IPlugin;

                    if (new_action != null)
                    {
                        InstalledPlugins.Add(PluginInfos);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Print(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

DLL for the Interface

```
public class PluginController
{
    public interface IPlugin
    {
        string PluginDescription { get; }
        void StartService(int ID);
    }
}
```

Plugin

```
using PluginController;
using PluginController.PluginController;

public class Plugin : IPlugin
{
    public string PluginDescription
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public void StartService(int ID)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The main app should start the plugin with a specified ID.
Every Plugin can do whatever it wants and should get some Information from the main app:
1. What is the database con if I need it?
2. What is the logpath?
3. Which plugins are installed
and so on...

I could pass the values within the method but I don't like the idea of passing several parameters if the plugin doesn't even want them.

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Your dll should just get the connection string from the .config file for the app and create a new instance of the connection..

Comment: What if the string is not saved in a config but user generated throug a form?
Let's say the user inputs all connection data and wants to start Plugin X with this connection?

Comment: Ideally the classes should receive those values by having them passed to them, often via the constructor, but perhaps also as method arguments. If those classes have to read config values from some file, then they only work if the app that loads them has those config values in that file. If they are passed as arguments then it doesn't matter where or how they are stored. Those classes don't care and shouldn't care. They just get the values they need and do their work.

Comment: It might be possible to suggest something more concrete if you show a little bit of how you load these classes and how you use them, as well as a little bit of code showing how those classes use the connection string.

Comment: I edited my top Post!
The connection was just an example. There are some information I want to share with my DLLs (see main post).